# Javascript check 'URL' is empty then populate with "" , else display url as hyperlink

Tags: javascript, if-statement, foreach, hyperlink, html-table

I have some Javascript that displays titles from an XML.

When the title is clicked the information associated with it will pop up. I am having trouble when URL is empty.
If it is empty I don't want the URL displayed. It should just look like URL.

If it is present I want the url displayed as a hyperlink.

I am new to this so please take it easy on me!

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<notepad>
  <nextID>114</nextID>
  <memos>
    <memo id="100">
      <title>Valentines</title>
      <sender>James Mcavoy</sender>
      <recipient>Clara Croft</recipient>
      <date>11/09/17</date>
      <message>Let me know what you would like for Valentines</message>
      <url>www.heresyourpresent.com</url>
    </memo>
    <memo id="101">
      <title>Birthday</title>
      <sender>Louise King</sender>
      <recipient>Lily May</recipient>
      <date>13/10/17</date>
      <message>I will be there for your birthday! What cake would you like?</message>
      <url>www.findmycake.com</url>
    </memo>
    <memo id="102">
      <title>Christmas</title>
      <sender>Monty Python</sender>
      <recipient>Jack Maloe</recipient>
      <date>16/11/17</date>
      <message>What would you like for Chrismtas Jack ?</message>
      <url>www.socksrus.co.uk</url>
    </memo>
    <memo id="103">
      <title>Easter</title>
      <sender>Carolyn Lynemouth</sender>
      <recipient>Mercedes Hugh</recipient>
      <date>30/04/17</date>
      <message>I got a few easter eggs for your daughter on this site, is this ok?</message>
      <url>www.eastereggs.com</url>
    </memo>
    <memo id="104">
      <title>Christening</title>
      <sender>Dylan Bramble</sender>
      <recipient>Kelly Love</recipient>
      <date>07/05/17</date>
      <message>I have sent you an e-voucher for a baby store</message>
      <url>www.firstchristening.com</url>
    </memo>
    <memo id="105">
      <title>Wedding</title>
      <sender>Polly Wisener</sender>
      <recipient>Natasha Kirkpatrick</recipient>
      <date>12/06/18</date>
      <message>Remember to go to attend the dress fitting please on Friday</message>
      <url>dgdfgdffg</url>
    </memo>
    <memo id="106">
      <title>Graduation</title>
      <sender>Kathryn Kirke</sender>
      <recipient>Cara Lovejoy</recipient>
      <date>04/07/18</date>
      <message>Just to let you know I can't make your graduation, sorry</message>
      <url>www.makegraduationspecial.co.uk</url>
    </memo>
    <memo id="107">
      <title>Anniversary</title>
      <sender>Eric Simpleton</sender>
      <recipient>Grainne Simpleton</recipient>
      <date>18/08/17</date>
      <message>Be at le maison restaurant at 7pm this Thursday. I have a table booked</message>
      <url>dfgdfgdfgfd</url>
    </memo>
    <memo id="108">
      <title>Baby Shower</title>
      <sender>Hyacinth Bouquet</sender>
      <recipient>Gemma Hamilton</recipient>
      <date>20/12/17</date>
      <message>I will attend your baby shower</message>
      <url>www.babygift.co.uk</url>
    </memo>
    <memo id="109">
      <title>Stag</title>
      <sender>John Smith</sender>
      <recipient>Cara Lovejoy</recipient>
      <date>22/12/17</date>
      <message>Your stag do will be in Marbella. I have your tickets</message>
      <url>www.thelaststag.co.uk</url>
    </memo>
    <memo id="110">
      <title>New Home</title>
      <sender>Opal Newfridge</sender>
      <recipient>Kylie Jenner</recipient>
      <date>19/07/17</date>
      <message>Congratulations on the new home. Can't wait for a cuppa</message>
      <url>www.newhomesforyou.com</url>
    </memo>
    <memo id="111">
      <title>Communion</title>
      <sender>John Smith</sender>
      <recipient>Hilary Clinton, Jacob Marks, Lilly Popper</recipient>
      <date>22/12/17</date>
      <message>Your stag do will be in Marbella. I have your tickets</message>
      <url>www.thelaststag.co.uk</url>
    </memo>
    <memo id="112">
      <title>Retirement Party</title>
      <sender>Kylie Jenner</sender>
      <recipient>Chloe Jenner, Rob Stark, Patrick Hunter, Julie Smith, Helen Doe</recipient>
      <date>22/07/17</date>
      <message>Please join us at Lodge Hotel for Robs Retirement Dinner</message>
      <url>www.lodge.com</url>
    </memo>
     <memo id="113">
      <title>Fathers Day</title>
      <sender>Carolyn Lynemouth</sender>
      <recipient>Rob Stark</recipient>
      <date>22/07/17</date>
      <message>We will be sending you away for the weekend to London!</message>
      <url>www.easyflights.com</url>
    </memo>
  </memos>
</notepad>
```

Code is below

```
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET", "memos.xml", false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDocument = xmlhttp.responseXML;
memos = xmlDocument.getElementsByTagName("memo");

table = "<tr><th>Title</th></tr>";
for (count = 0; count < memos.length; count++) {
  table += "<tr onclick='displayTitle(" + count + ")'><td>";
  table += memos[count].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
  table += "</td>";
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;

function displayTitle(count) {

  document.getElementById("showTitle").innerHTML =
    "ID: " +
    memos[count].getAttribute("id") +
    "<br>Title: " +
    memos[count].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "<br>Sender: " +
    memos[count].getElementsByTagName("sender")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "<br>Recipient: " +
    memos[count].getElementsByTagName("recipient")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "<br>Date: " +
    memos[count].getElementsByTagName("date")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "<br>Message: " +
    memos[count].getElementsByTagName("message")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "<br>Url: " +
    urlNode = memos[count].getElementsByTagName("url")[0];
  if (urlNode.hasChildNodes()) {
    url = urlNode.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
  } else {
    url = "";
  }

}
```

Comment: What happens when the code you posted runs? A question should always say what you expect to happen, and what actually happens. It would also help answerers if you post an example of the xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to set your url to "" after you already updated the innerHTML?

```
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET", "memos.xml", false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDocument = xmlhttp.responseXML; 
memos = xmlDocument.getElementsByTagName("memo");

table="<tr><th>Title</th></tr>";
for (count = 0; count <memos.length; count++) { 
  table += "<tr onclick='displayTitle(" + count + ")'><td>";
  table += memos[count].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
  table += "</td>";
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;

function displayTitle(count) {
    var urlNode = memos[count].getElementsByTagName("url")[0];
    var url = "";
    if (urlNode.hasChildNodes()) {
        url = urlNode.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    } else {
        url = "";
    }

    document.getElementById("showTitle").innerHTML =
  "ID: " +
  memos[count].getAttribute("id")+
   "<br>Title: " +
  memos[count].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
  "<br>Sender: " +
  memos[count].getElementsByTagName("sender")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
  "<br>Recipient: " + 
  memos[count].getElementsByTagName("recipient")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
  "<br>Date: " + 
  memos[count].getElementsByTagName("date")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
   "<br>Message: " + 
  memos[count].getElementsByTagName("message")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
  "<br>Url: " + url;       

}
```

Comment: I tried something similar earlier and then scrapped it! Thank you so much

Comment: @P.Smith So it's working as intended now? If so please accept my post as answer. And in the future declare and assing values to your variables before trying to use them in html, these are the absolute basics.